# How can I break on warnings in the perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have a codepath that sometimes emits warnings. Since this path is used a lot of times I don't want to break on each pass. How can I break only on times it emits warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "signal handler" for warnings and set a flag, then break when the flag is set.

```
our $warn_flag = 0;
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { $warn_flag = 1; CORE::warn(@_) };

...

for $i (1 .. 1_000_000_000) {
    do_something_that_might_warn();
    $DB::single ||= $warn_flag;
    $warn_flag = 0;
}
```

Comment: I only added `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { $DB::single = 1; CORE::warn(@_) };` And used `s` in the debugger to step back to the place I want.

Comment: That'll work, too, if you don't mind having to step out of the signal handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings qw(FATAL);
```

This will convert warnings to errors in the lexical scope, which will automatically cause the debugger to break.